# Malformed Mach-o file after hex editing mac binary file

Tags: macos, hex, edit, binaryfiles

I'm trying to edit this binary file on my mac using a hex editor and all I do is change the path to the libraries it depends on to another path that also contains those libraries. When I save the binary file and try to run it in Terminal I get this message: **Malformed Mach-o file**

Why is this happening I don't understand? Its just a simple path change and its all letters, I mean its not some gibberish code like most of the binary file. Should work in principle but its not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you use a hex editor to change a library path ? Use correct tool to do this kind of things. Just check the man page of install_name_tool.

Comment: I want the binary file and all its necessary libraries/files to be in the SAME directory. So I can make it portable. I need to share it later with other people and I don't want them running into problems ie. "missing libraries etc". I'll check out this man page u speak of thx